# Why tables's td node.appendChild doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript function to create a table with image cells:

```
    function Draw(array) {
        // get the reference for the body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        document.clear();

        // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.setAttribute("borderstyle", "1");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            // creates a table row
            var row = document.createElement("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
                // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
                // the end of the table row
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createElement(array[4 * j + i]);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }

            // add the row to the end of the table body
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        // put the <tbody> in the <table>
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
    }
```

but in

```
var cellText = document.createElement(array[4 * j + i]);
cell.appendChild(cellText);
row.appendChild(cell);
```

the `cell.appendChild(cellText);` doesn't work!
I don't know why and I don't know how to resolve it!

**update**
the a array is this:

```
    var a = Array(16);
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        a[i] = '<img src="' + i + '.jpg" />';
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is in array[4 * j + i] ?

Comment: @eis: the array that includes the string of the `<img ...`, It's my images tag value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Re your comment:

> It just put a text. it means I see the text of `<img src ...` not the image!

It would have been useful if you'd told us that `array[4 * j + i]` contained *markup* (included an example of it in the question, for instance).

If the array contains *markup*, you don't want to create a new node of any kind. Instead, assign to `innerHTML` of the table cell:

```
cell.innerHTML = array[4 * j + i];
row.appendChild(cell);
```

When you assign to `innerHTML`, the browser parses the markup and adds the relevant content to the element.

---

**Original answer** before the comment below and before `array`'s content was given:

To create a text node, you use [`createTextNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1975348127), not `createElement`. So:

```
// Change here ---------v
var cellText = document.createTextNode(array[4 * j + i]);
cell.appendChild(cellText);
row.appendChild(cell);
```

Suppose `array[4 * j + i]` was `"Hi there"`. Your `document.createElement(array[4 * j + i])` call was asking the DOM to create an *element* with the tag name `Hi there`, exactly the way that `document.createElement('div')` asks it to create an element with the tag name `div`.

Comment: It just put a text. it means I see the text of `<img src ...` in the cells not the image!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: You didn't tell us what the content of `array[4 * j +i]` was. The more effort you put into the question, the more useful the answers you'll get will be. I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: I tried `innerHTML` this way: `cell.innerHTML(array[4 * j + i]);` but it doesn't worked too!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee well, you shouldn't have tried it that way, but instead like cell.innerHTML = array[4 * j + i] which was suggested.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: `innerHTML` isn't a function, it's a property. If you use it as shown in the answer, that will work.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: **It's right there in the answer:** `cell.innerHTML = array[4 * j + i];`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's some other alternatives to the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569943/365237), if you'd prefer to use appendChild() instead of innerHTML property.

You could've also done

```
var a = Array(16);
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    a[i] = document.createElement('img');
    a[i].setAttribute('src', i + '.jpg');
}
```

and it would've worked too. Also, you could've created an Image object:

```
var a = Array(16);
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    a[i] = new Image();
    a[i].src = i + '.jpg';
}
```

and appendChild should've still worked.

Another usable, but completely different approach would've been to use a javascript framework, such as jQuery, and its functionalities. That would require rewriting the code you have however.